# Android Notification : perform task in place by clicking notification. Do not launch an activity

Tags: android, android-notifications

My application adds a notification in the notification bar. Now when user clicks the notification, is there a way to execute some code inplace rather than control is redirected back to my app.

Let the user be in notification area after clicking this notification and the click does the work in some background task or service.
Is it possible to send a handler message in this case

Update to question:
If I wish to have 2 buttons in the notification. where would the handling code run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be an easy one. Just use an IntentService:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

and here the first tutorial I found on google:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/

Comment: thanks. So if I were to add a remote view, with 2 buttons, the handling of click events would be done in this service, how wuld the code flow ?

Comment: I thought you wanna do this without any views and activities? You would add the Intent (which is handled by the IntentServices's onHandleIntent and is defined in the broadcast receiver) to the notification. Does that answer your question?